# html5-qrcode does not work in PDF_417 format, i want to scan argentinian DNI

Tags: javascript, pdf417

This is my config:

```
var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
            "reader", { 
              fps: 10, 
              qrbox: { width: 400, height: 400 },
              formatsToSupport: [ Html5QrcodeSupportedFormats.PDF_417 ],
              experimentalFeatures: { useBarCodeDetectorIfSupported: true },
              useBarCodeDetectorIfSupported: true
            });
```

I looked for a lot of libraries but none work.